# Messed Up MariaDB... Cannot Reset It

Tags: mariadb

I had a mariaDB install and I messed up the root password. Now I can't get in. I've tried every tutorial to reset the password and only get ERROR 1045 (access denied for user 'root').

So I purged my install. I ran sudo mysql_secure_installation and I'm still getting this error 1045.

I could really use some help. I don't care if the DB's are gone, I just want to be able to use MariaDB and I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the manual page on "skip-grant-tables"?

Comment: Hi! Yes! It didn't work. What I did do was super-ultra purge. I purged every mysql/mariadb package i could find. I manually removed the /etc/mysql folder and the var/whatevermariadbfolder I could find. 

After crash and burn i was able to totally reset and get back in.

Answer (score 0):

What I did do was super-ultra purge. I purged every mysql/mariadb package i could find. I manually removed the /etc/mysql folder and the var/whatevermariadbfolder I could find. After crash and burn i was able to totally reset and get back in.